# Issue with Dalli not working as expectd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached, dalli, celluloid

I have a simple rails app and I am trying to save and retrieve keys from a memcache box, which was working for a long time  unless we started encountering the error below, I have tried debugging this but will need someone to help now

```
[2015-10-28 12:25:46.649][ERROR] Unexpected exception during Dalli request: NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (pid:58452)
[2015-10-28 12:25:46.649][ERROR] /Users/aupadhyay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/celluloid-0.17.2/lib/celluloid/proxy/async.rb:28:in `method_missing'
/Users/aupadhyay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load'
```

Let me know incase anyone has insights to this ?

Comment: without some code i don't think someone can help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.